# Facebook api for facebook integration of a GWT application?

Tags: facebook, gwt, playn

I need to integrate facebook in my playN game(gwt). The user should be able to login to facebook and get the friendlist, online presence and so on.

Can any on please suggest some of the facebook apis for this?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using [socialauth](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/) in your GWT backend code.  I currently use this for G+ and Facebook integration server side.

Comment: After searching for some days I found these too.

gwtFb, 

GwtGaeFb